# Steam client does not remember my password

Tags: steam, ubuntu

Although "Remember my password" option is checked on login window and "Don't save account credentials on this computer" option is unchecked,  Steam client does not remember my login password. I have to enter my password (not my user name) whenever Steam starts.

I have two computers. I face this issue on Ubuntu 16.10 64 Bit. It can remember my password on my other computer, which has Windows 10 64 Bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a VPN or your IP changes everytime this can happen.

I am using a VPN and everytime I change my location or turn it off I have the same situation like you.
Try to establish the VPN connection before you start Steam and use the same exit-node (same IP), then it works most the time for me.

Comment: Yes, I use VPN. Could you find any solution for this?

Comment: @dx486 Note that using a VPN on Steam is technically against the Steam Terms of Service. It's not supported, and they cannot support it because it could cause them trouble regarding regional trade and licensing restrictions. For example, they cannot be active in certain countries because of trade embargoes, and they cannot sell games in countries where those games are banned due to local legislation.

Comment: @Nzall Thanks for letting me know. In fact I don't use VPN for Steam. I will look for a way to let Steam make connections bypassing VPN.

Comment: @dx486 If I am using the same exit node and start steam after the VPN connection is established it works fine.

Comment: @Nzall Even with VPN I am using my "local country" store, so it's no problem with the Terms of Service. But generally this is a point you need to be aware of, that's true.